# Updating a flag in AWS S3 for consumption by Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

First, I probably lack the accurate data terminology to describe my issue. Please bear with me.

Daily or monthly, we're loading data into S3 (partitioned by `year=`,`month=`,`day=`). The s3 object is in the form a csv format (not sure if it matters). These are source files. There's minor ETL done, then data is loaded to back to s3. An Athena table is used to access the target data.

The final table has a column that tracks active or historical records (let's call it: `record_status`). This column is created in the ETL (it's not coming from the source file, but uses information passed through from the source file).

When a duplicate record is uploaded to s3 source file, we need to change the record_status field for the target s3 file so that `record_status = Historical` while the new record = `Active`.

Typically, on-premises I would have the data in a relational table and our ETL tool would just scan the table and update the old record so `record_status = Historical` and write the new record with a `record_status = Active`.

Where I'm struggling with AWS S3 is that the target objects are stored not stored in a "database". It's a file system storage. The target objects are loaded to s3 partitioned as `year=,month=,day=` as well (similar to source s3). An ETL process would need to scan every single S3 target object and then re-create the entire object in which the historical record is stored. This is because I don't think we have the ability to just scan the s3 object and update a single row in the file.

I'm asking for general guidance in this case. To me, it seems like the fact that we're storing target files in S3 is a limitation.

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't put the result data in a relational database (e.g. RDS)?

Comment: @FilippoTestini None that I am aware of -- perhaps just lack of experience and ignorance on our part on what to do.

Comment: @FilippoTestini would it be accurate to that for this type of change data capture, we would need to store the data in a relational database first?

Answer (score 0):

If your individual record is large enough, you can actually partition S3 like `s3://bucket/year/month/day/recordId/your_record_id.json` and enable bucket versioning, so all you will have to do is to upload only the new record and S3 will automatically [version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/RetMetaOfObjVersion.html) it.